# Prevent default duplicate email rejection in Meteor account creation

Tags: javascript, meteor, accounts

I am building an application that has two types of users. Professional users and their clients. The account types are completely distinct with no overlap. So, emails registered as Pro could still be used to register as a Client, and if a Pro user tried to log in using the client form, their account would not exist.

The problem:
Meteor automatically prevents duplicate emails from being used when creating user accounts. My thought was to use a custom validation to allow the behavior and essentially create two different sets of users. Here is an example of the validation I tried for a 'Pro' user.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
var email = user.email;
   if (Meteor.users.find({emails: email, isPro : true}).count() > 0) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, "This email address is already registered");
   }
   user.isPro = true;
   return user;
```

});

But meteor still uses its default duplicate email rejection instead. Any ideas on how I can override this behavior, or is there a better way to create two distinct sets of users?

Comment: Do you really need or want separate user documents though? What would the issue be with having 2 flags in the user object isPro and isClient? You could have a isPro or isClient flag passed in with the Accounts.createUser function client side depending on where the user signs up or what options they select. Then once they have signed up you have an option for them somewhere to become the other type of user. Maybe this isn't suitable but I just think you will run into issues even if this is possible by having 2 separate documents for the same person.

Comment: This could work, it just wouldn't be ideal in my mind. Pro users and Client users are completely distinct. A Client user will never be converted to a Pro user and vice versa. I think the easiest situation would be to have a completely separate database table for each user type. I'm just not sure if that is possible, so I was trying to make it work.

Comment: I just think it might be problematic though. If a user is a client and pro with 2 accounts and they use the same email address and the same password (which would be likely) then when they sign in how do you know which account you should sign them into? I don't see anyway to pass in pro or client login to the Meteor.loginWithPassword function. Also if a pro wants to look at their client stuff they will need to sign out and sign back in right? Maybe you could have 2 collections Clients and Professionals and store the user's _id in it. That way you have just 1 user document but your 2 collections

Comment: I appreciate your input. It could work. I'll have to think about that!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a mongo shell

```
 db.users.dropIndex('emails.address_1');
```

Doing this is probably not the best idea and may have unintended consequences. I too think the solution discussed in the comments would be better.